# Why does lodash have gt, lt, gte, lte functions?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any interesting use for these functions that can be helpful instead of just using the comparison operators? For example, https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#gte

I am just wondering if there is a value in these functions that I am missing since it does not make sense (at least for me) to include them in a library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions can be passed as arguments or chained with other functions; operators cannot.

This makes those "operator" functions composable, amenable to a more functional approach.